# SoundCloud Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

I have this source code for an mp3 download app, and it worked fine last time I used it, few months ago. Now when I try it, it gives me an error, when I click on a song to download it, from search results. Here's the error:

```
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): Process: com.soundload, PID: 2075
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean de.voidplus.soundcloud.Track.isStreamable()' on a null object reference
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.baixavideos.Downloader.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:41)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.baixavideos.Downloader.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:1)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-01 13:06:09.227: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-01 13:06:11.353: W/System.err(2174): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-01 13:06:11.353: W/System.err(2174):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
08-01 13:06:11.354: W/System.err(2174):     at de.voidplus.soundcloud.SoundCloud.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-01 13:06:11.354: W/System.err(2174):     at com.baixavideos.ui.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:63)
08-01 13:06:11.354: W/System.err(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
08-01 13:06:11.354: W/System.err(2174):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
08-01 13:06:11.354: W/System.err(2174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
```

Downloader.java:

```
package com.baixavideos;

import com.baixavideos.ui.SongDetails;

import de.voidplus.soundcloud.SoundCloud;
import de.voidplus.soundcloud.Track;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Track>{

    private int id;
    private SoundCloud soundcloud;
    private SongDetails ui;

    public Downloader(){
        soundcloud = new SoundCloud("cd07b57592f6d914f437f8ab2856363d", "841953bd718a3ceb427b3e3be170a014"); 
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Downloader setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Track doInBackground(String... arg0) {        
        Track track = soundcloud.getTrack(getId());
        return track;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Track track) {
        super.onPostExecute(track);

        if(track.isStreamable()){
            getUi().onSongLoaded(track);
        } else {
            getUi().onStreamingError();
        }
    }

    public SongDetails getUi() {
        return ui;
    }

    public Downloader setUi(SongDetails ui) {
        this.ui = ui;

        return this;
    }   

}
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like permission issues for your temp directory for your app. Your app can only put files into it's own app directory and for some reason permission is getting denied. That's why it's essentially failing ultimately in the isStreamable() being null.

Also have you tried adding permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE></uses-permission>
```

Also onPostExecute() you should do a check to see if track!=null, then catch the error and log it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code worked few months ago without any issues. I have several apps like this one and all have the same issue now.

Comment: What versions of Android are you using? 5.0?

Comment: 5.1.1 on one app. 5.0.1 on the other. I tried with 4.4.4 but it's the same.

Comment: I'm starting to think that something happened with the soundcloud API. Do they also have a RESTful service you can digest?

Comment: Me too. I don't know actually.